# UseEffect() keeps giving error for Redirection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks

If login is successful, a token is returned and is stored in the local storage. In this case, I should redirect to a private route /panel. If login is unsuccessful, I should be able to show the error message from `ShowError()`. The error message functionality was working properly before I added the redirection.

This is my LoginPage.tsx

```
function LoginPage (){
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  }); 

 const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

function ShowError(){
  if (!localStorage.getItem('token'))
  {
    console.log('Login Not Successful');
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={colortheme}>
    <Typography color='primary'>
      Login Unsuccessful
      </Typography>
      </ThemeProvider>)
  }
}

function FormSubmitted(){
  setSubmitted(true);
  console.log('Form submitted');
}

function RedirectionToPanel(){
  if(submitted && localStorage.getItem('token')){
    return <Redirect to='/panel'/>
  }
}

// useEffect(() => {
//   if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
//     return <Redirect to='/panel'/>
//   }
// },[] );

  function submitForm(LoginMutation: any) {
    const { email, password } = state;
    if(email && password){
      LoginMutation({
        variables: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
    })
    .catch(console.log)
    }
  }

    return (
      <Mutation mutation={LoginMutation}>
        {(LoginMutation: any) => (
          <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div style={{
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
              <Avatar>
                <LockOutlinedIcon />
              </Avatar>
              <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                Sign in
              </Typography>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    actions.setSubmitting(false);
                  }, 1000);
                }}
                validationSchema={schema}
              >
                {props => {
                  const {
                    values: { email, password },
                    errors,
                    touched,
                    handleChange,
                    isValid,
                    setFieldTouched
                  } = props;
                  const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
                    e.persist();                
                    handleChange(e);
                    setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
                    setState( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   [name]: e.target.value }));  
                  };
                  return (
                    <form style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                    onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                    submitForm(LoginMutation);FormSubmitted();RedirectionToPanel()}}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="email"
                        fullWidth
                        name="email"
                        helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                        error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                        label="Email"     
                        value={email}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        fullWidth
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ""}
                        error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "password")}
                      /> 
                      {submitted && ShowError()}

                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                        label="Remember me"
                      />
                      <br />
                      <Button className='button-center'
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={!isValid || !email || !password}
                        // onClick={handleOpen}
                        style={{
                          background: '#6c74cc',
                          borderRadius: 3,
                          border: 0,
                          color: 'white',
                          height: 48,
                          padding: '0 30px'
                        }}
                      >                       
                        Submit</Button>
                      <br></br>
                      <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs>
                          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                            Forgot password?
                          </Link>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                            {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                          </Link>
                        </Grid>                    
                      </Grid>
                    </form>
                  )
                }}
              </Formik>
            </div>
            {submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}
          </Container>
          )
        }
      </Mutation>
    );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Currently, if the login is unsuccessful, it automatically redirects to page /404. However, I want it to direct to /404 only if an invalid/private link is entered. In case of unsuccessful login, I want to show the error message.

I also tried to use `UseEffect()`, which is commented out in the code above but it keeps giving me this error on the arrow:

```
Argument of type '() => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => void | undefined)'.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => void | undefined)'.
      Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '() => void | undefined'.
        Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(): void | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

here is how my private routing is implemented in the App.tsx

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

const PrivateRoute = ({component, isAuthenticated, ...rest}: any) => {
  const routeComponent = (props: any) => (
      isAuthenticated
          ? React.createElement(component, props)
          : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/404'}}/>
  );
  return <Route {...rest} render={routeComponent}/>;
};
```

If I comment out the `{submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>}`, I get the error message on unsuccessful login but then there's no redirection even when the login is successful.

**Edited Code:**

```
function LoginPage (){
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  }); 

 const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
 const [shouldRedirect, setShouldRedirect] = useState(false);

function ShowError(){
  if (!localStorage.getItem('token'))
  {
    console.log('Login Not Successful');
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={colortheme}>
    <Typography color='primary'>
      Login Unsuccessful
      </Typography>
      </ThemeProvider>)
  }
}

// function FormSubmitted(){
//   setSubmitted(true);
//   console.log('Form submitted');
// }

function RedirectionToPanel(){
  console.log('check');
  if(submitted && localStorage.getItem('token')){
    console.log('Finall');
    return <Redirect to='/panel'/>
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
    if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
      setShouldRedirect(true);
    }
  },[] );


  function submitForm(LoginMutation: any) {
    setSubmitted(true);
    const { email, password } = state;
    if(email && password){
      LoginMutation({
        variables: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
    })
    .catch(console.log)
    }
  }
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={LoginMutation}>
        {(LoginMutation: any) => (
          <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div style={{
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
              <Avatar>
                <LockOutlinedIcon />
              </Avatar>
              <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                Sign in
              </Typography>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    actions.setSubmitting(false);
                  }, 1000);
                }}
                validationSchema={schema}
              >
                {props => {
                  const {
                    values: { email, password },
                    errors,
                    touched,
                    handleChange,
                    isValid,
                    setFieldTouched
                  } = props;
                  const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
                    e.persist();                
                    handleChange(e);
                    setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
                    setState( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   [name]: e.target.value }));  
                  };
                  return (
                    <form style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                    onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                    submitForm(LoginMutation);RedirectionToPanel()}}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="email"
                        fullWidth
                        name="email"
                        helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                        error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                        label="Email"     
                        value={email}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        fullWidth
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ""}
                        error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "password")}
                      /> 
                      {submitted && ShowError()}

                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                        label="Remember me"
                      />
                      <br />
                      <Button className='button-center'
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={!isValid || !email || !password}
                        // onClick={handleOpen}
                        style={{
                          background: '#6c74cc',
                          borderRadius: 3,
                          border: 0,
                          color: 'white',
                          height: 48,
                          padding: '0 30px'
                        }}
                      >                       
                        Submit</Button>
                    </form>
                  )
                }}
              </Formik>
            </div>
            {/* {submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>} */}
          </Container>
          )
        }
      </Mutation>
    );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that returning `Redirect` component shouldn't be called in `useEffect` hook or inside any function.
You should have something like that:

```
function LoginPage (){
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  }); 
  const [shouldRedirect, setShouldRedirect] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      setShouldRedirect(true);
    }
  }, []);


  function submitForm(LoginMutation: any) {
    setSubmitted(true);
    const { email, password } = state;
    if(email && password){
      LoginMutation({
          variables: {
          email: email,
          password: password,
        },
     }).then(({ data }: any) => {
       localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
       setShouldRedirect(true);
     })
    .catch(console.log)
   }
  }
  if(shouldRedirect) return <Redirect to="/panel" />;
  return (
   ... rest of code
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you please see my edited code in the qs and guide me where to use the ```if(shouldRedirect)```statement in my case? If I use it above my return, it gives an error.

Comment: @a125 what is the error you have when you use it above your return?

Comment: ```Failed to compile.

./src/pages/login/LoginPage.tsx
  Line 269:24:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions```

Comment: @a125 This might be because you didn't write the redirect component in the same line with return function like what I have done.
  `if(shouldRedirect) return <Redirect to "/panel" />;`

Comment: I still get ```Identifier expected.ts(1003)
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)```on the ```/panel```

Comment: @a125 oh, I forgot to add `=`. It should be `<Redirect to="/panel" />`. 
I have updated my answer

Comment: There's still no redirection in case of successful login. It compiles without an error but a yellow dot starts appearing on my visual studio file

Comment: @a125 aha, that's because useEffect has no dependencies so it is fired one time only after the component been mounted. I have edited the code to make dependency for useEffect which is `localStorage.getItem('token')`

Comment: That doesn't work either. And as soon as I put the ```[localStorage.getItem('token')]```in the useEffect, I get the yellow dot. See how I am using token in the App.tsx file. Maybe the error is there

Comment: @a125, hmmm, yeah, I am mistaken in the last edit because only state and props change can let the component re-render and thus useEffect can fire. I edited the code and removed useEffect and added setShouldRedirect inside the submitForm function. This should work I guess.

Comment: I didn't encounter that you will need to first check if the token is stored or not in local storage so I will add useEffect hook again with no dependencies so it fires one time only after the component mounted

Comment: it kinda works but not fully. So the error message works fine but when the token is returned, initially I am returned to the /404 page instead of /panel. However, if I try again and go to the login page, I am redirected to /panel successful. I think we're close. So maybe the problem is that redirection works now but the token is coming late so instead of /panel we go to /404?

Comment: @a125 you should remove your  RedirectionToPanel function and remove its calling from here:  `submitForm(LoginMutation);RedirectionToPanel()}}>`

Comment: In the submitForm function, can you remove 
`setShouldRedirect(true);`
and replace it with 
`props.history.push("/panel");`

Comment: 'cannot find props'

Comment: `function LoginPage (props)`
I am just debugging with you. but the first solution should work fully. Please do console.log and do some debugging

Comment: The problem is still the same. It goes to /404 at first. But then If I go to LoginPage again, it takes me to /panel

Comment: See the App.tsx file code. I am using /404 in case the path is invalid

Comment: Then the issue isn't here. You should check isAuthenticated prop when it returns true , how and when it is checked, ...etc. Needs some debugging at your end.